# Local class can access non-final variable in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, local-class

Before Java 8, We were not able to use non-final variables inside local class. But now they are allowing final as well as effectively final(who's values has not been changed), can be referred by local classes. What i know(Correct me if i am wrong), they didn't supported referring non-final values because there values can be changed. So, how they are supporting it now and why it was not supported earlier.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The situation has not changed at all, actually. The compiler is just a bit smarter, and doesn't force you to use the final keyword anymore.

If it detects that the variable is *effectively* final, i.e. assigned only once, and never after, everything is good. If it detects that it's not effectively final, it refuses to compile.

So, instead of forcing you to make a variable final, it detects it automatically. But you still can't use non-effectively-final variables inside an inner class or lambda.